# 1045 Can't Connect To DB with Laravel Valet

Tags: valet

I can connect to a Craft 3 site just fine using Laravel Valet, but when I attempt to get a Craft 2 site working with it, it gives me this in the log:

```
[exception.CDbException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Visiting the site with the /index.php?p=admin portion appended to the url gives this:

```
Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.
```

I 100% have the correct db credentials, as the Craft 3 site is using the same ones and is running just fine at sitename.test

```
'http://example.test' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'thecorrectpw',
    'database' => 'dbname',
)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? I would like to keep using Valet as it makes my life easier, but I am going to fling my laptop out the window into the city streets in about an hour or so if I cant get this working =)

Comment: did u check if it does work with `'*' =>  array(...`

Comment: I did not. I need to get stuff done today so I uninstalled Valet. Going to have to give this a shot again perhaps next week.

Comment: it usually works out of the box with valet, i did always use multi-env though https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-multi-environment

Comment: Could Craft 2 somehow be using an older version of MySQL with different creds?

https://gist.github.com/benlinton/d24471729ed6c2ace731 usually saves me with similar problems.

Comment: I will look into this. You are prob on the money with this one. Might have some time later on in the week, and I will get back to you.

Comment: You sir win the Golden Ticket to the Willy Wonka CraftCMS factory. My current(terrible setup) was using the built in mysql provided with mac, so when I tried using Valet, which relies on Homebrew, Valet obviously must have been trying to use the mysql version in homebrew. I put an end to using the built in mysql on mac, and installed the latest version of mysql via homebrew, and now everything works fine.